# How to sample from a multivariate empirical distribution

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis, random-generation, copula

Recently, I’m working on the multivariate conditional estimation issue. Considering $2n$ variables:

$$\{X_{1},X_{2},\dots,X_{n},Y_{1},Y_{2},\dots,Y_{n}\}$$

where each follows an empirical distribution through fitting the corresponding dataset. Thus, we can obtain the joint distribution **F**J using Copula. If given

$$X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2},\dots X_{n}=x_{n}$$

we can also derive the conditional joint distribution

$$F\{Y_{1},Y_{2},\dots,Y_{n}|X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2},\dots,X_{n}=x_{n}\}$$

for $Y_{1},Y_{2},\dots,Y_{n}$.

Now, I want to generate random vectors for $\{Y_{1},Y_{2},\dots,Y_{n}\}$ based on $F\{Y_{1},Y_{2},\dots,Y_{n}|X_{1}=x_{1},X_{2}=x_{2},\dots,X_{n}=x_{n}\}$.

How can I achieve this? This problem has perplexed me for a long while.

Comment: You want to sample from the copla or from empirical distribution? In the second case you simply draw integer from $1$ to $n$ and then take $x_i,y_i$ as your draw - this is how bootstrap works.

Comment: @Tim thanks for your answer. Actually, I want to sample from the conditional joint distribution, can you explain a little bit more on your comment, since I'm not very familiar with bootstrap, thanks a lot.

Comment: @SJ.STEVEN what he means is that you can sample from a set of indices instead of the original data because your data could be viewed as an ordered tuple. For example, randomly picking a number $i$ would be sampling $\left(x_{i},y_{i}\right)$. Repeat this step $n$ times and you will have gotten a sample of size $n$.

Comment: What is the size of your data set? How many points? Dimension of each point ($n$)? If your sample only sparsely fills the data space, then straight bootstrapping would be misleading. For continuous data, sampling the conditional PDF via simple bootstrapping would likely be essentially impossible. (Is there a variant where you add noise to the data and effectively sample from a kernel density estimate?)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 The size of my data set is around 5000 for each variable, I used empirical distribution fitting for each variable.

Comment: If each variable has a Gaussian distribution, the conditional probability will also be a Gaussian distribution as well. Really, this is a particular case.

Comment: look for "empirical copula"